Should I forward Oauth2 JWT token
In Oauth2, user (React SPA) authenticates with the auhtorization server, social login for example. SPA receive the token after several redirects, stores it in-memory and includes it into auhtorization header when accessing resource server (REST-api). Resource server validates the token using provider. Is this correct understanding of token authentication?
Let's say the rest-api calls internal microservices in the same transaction. Is it good practice to retrieve a token dedicated for each service account (losing context of the end user), or should I forward the original token?
I'm also puzzled how to preserve react application state over redirects.

You should design each API to require particular scopes, like sales or whatever your business area is. Then, grant the client the scopes it needs to call APIs. This enables you to forward an access token between services while securely maintaining the user identity and other values.
In some cases, you may consider that this gives the upstream API too many privileges, eg if you only partially trust that API. In such cases, use OAuth Token Exchange from RFC 8693 to get a new access token for the sane user with reduced scopes to send to the upstream API.
You should not use the client credentials flow when a user is present and APIs operate on a user identity.
